# FETCH ERROR : request to https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/releases.json failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error, while hosting my REACT-APP using firebase. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?
I read somewhere about setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED to 0, but don't know exactly how to implement it.

Here's a snip of my terminal :-
[Img-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVYx5.png)

[Img-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1aWk.png)

I am using VS code, I'm getting this error while hosting my REACT app using firebase.

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of the code causing the issue? And maybe add some debugging details like where this code is being run, etc?

Comment: I added some debugging details. Do you know how to solve this issue?